# Need assistance with java homework?

Tags: java

I have this extremely crucial homework assignment and I literally dont have the time to do it, and am lacking in some knowledge in order to complete it because my teacher didn't go over it properly.
I haven't had enough time to do it, and I dont have much time remaining to do it or research things that would be beneficial to me and this is my only hope.
Can anyone please help me with this assignment in at least starting it off or possibly completing it.
**If anyone can complete it I will literally pay you through paypal, I'm just running out of options.**
Here is the assignment.

First instruction is :

"The following UML diagram describe 3 classes and the relationship between them. A firm has several
employees. Different type of employee exist. A contracted employee, as opposed to volunteer, is a type of
employee.
Using the information of the UML diagram and the description of each element, write the 3 classes Firm,
Staff and Contracted. "

Instruction 2:
[image]
Instruction 3:
[image]

Comment: Yep I will do it for USD120 per hour and please let me know when you need a job

Comment: please do not post external links thank you

Comment: @abcOfJava For USD 120 per hour I will take external links

Comment: @ScaryWombat lol rather don't have a virus in my computer than a $120 itself have you tried `kali linux` ?

Comment: I'll do it for USD130 per hour, but I'll probably take longer than Scary Wombat would.

Comment: @DavidWallace but with less bugs I am sure

Comment: OP - are bugs OK?

Comment: I'm doing a special on bugs today.  I'll throw in half a dozen for free.

Comment: Look I need the program to be spotless, I just dont know enough money to pay you 120 dollars im only 17 years old

Comment: so make a start, and when you have some trouble, ask the friendly folk here

Comment: How long would it take you to do the whole assignment?

Comment: Look, Wombat and I are not serious.  I don't think anybody here is going to help you cheat on your homework.  The purpose of homework is so that you learn something.  Handing it in late is better than having someone else do it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free-lance contracting marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Here is a freebee:

```
public class Staff {

    private int idNumber;
    private String department;

    public Staff() {
        idNumber = 127001;
        department = "TBD";
    }

    public Staff(int idNumber, String department) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Staff) {
            Staff sObj = (Staff) obj;
            return sObj.idNumber == this.idNumber;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Now you need to extend `Staff` for the `Contractor` class, and create the `Firm` class - really it should only take you an hour.

Comment: Whom are you helping by removing the learning opportunity that Aramcho213's parents have paid for?

Comment: I was hoping to provide just the `most` minimal amount to give him a leg up - have I helped too much?

Comment: I feel you have, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Im completely behind in class because of ulterior reasons, I dont know any of the material which is why I was asking if anyone would be kind enough to do it for me which i know is far fetched. I'm trying to do as much as I can with the information you just gave me but Im stumped. I appreciate your help though man I really do, but I think Im just going to fail I was just asking for some empathy but I know I'm not going to get any of that here, I've failed myself.

Comment: maybe go and speak to your instructor, they are not all evil ;-) some even have empathy